# Positioning multiple objects and creating texts in a canvas in React Three Fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to create multiple icosahedron geometry objects with a subtext under each object, which I have achieved by generating a new canvas for every item as shown below the post.

The issue with this is the limit of objects that can be displayed on the website. I am trying to figure out a way to do something similar but on a single canvas to avoid this problem but am not sure how to:

1. Position the created objects so that they are spaced evenly apart, and move to a new line if object goes outside of the canvas.
2. Create text inside the canvas.

During my attempt, I have managed to generate every object into a single canvas, however I was unable to reposition them and all of them just stacked at the same position. Thanks for the help in advance.

*Result*
[image: Output]

*Main.jsx*

```
import React from "react";
import { BallCanvas } from "./canvas";
import { items } from "../constants";

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-center gap-10">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div className='w-28 h-28' key={item.name}>
          <BallCanvas />
          <p className="text-[#646e7c] font-bold text-[12px]" style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
            Text
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

*Ball.jsx*

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import {
  Float,
  OrbitControls,
  Preload
} from "@react-three/drei";

import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";

const Ball = (props) => {
  return (
    <Float speed={1.75} rotationIntensity={1} floatIntensity={2}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.25} />
      <directionalLight position={[0, 0, 0.05]} />
      <mesh castShadow receiveShadow scale={2.75}>
        <icosahedronGeometry args={[1, 1]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial
          color="#CEDEBD"
          polygonOffset
          polygonOffsetFactor={-5}
          flatShading
        />
      </mesh>
    </Float>
  );
};

const BallCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas
      frameLoop="demand"
      dpr={[1, 2]}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
        <Ball />
      </Suspense>
      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default BallCanvas;
```

*Loader.jsx*

```
import { Html, useProgress } from "@react-three/drei";

const Loader = () => {
  const { progress } = useProgress();

  return (
    <Html>
      <span className='canvas-load'></span>
      <p
        style={{
          fontSize: 14,
          color: '#f1f1f1',
          fontWeight: 800,
          marginTop: 40
        }}
      >{progress.toFixed(2)}%</p>
    </Html>
  );
};

export default Loader;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `View` components from @react-three/drei with a single `Canvas`, yet still have multiple scenes that are ready to be styled w /css.

```
import React, { useMemo, useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { View, PerspectiveCamera, OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";

export default function App() {
  const views = useMemo(() => Array.from({ length: 30 }, React.createRef), []);
  //console.log(views);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "relative",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr",
        gap: "1rem",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      {views.map((view, i) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={i}
            ref={view}
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", overflow: "hidden" }}
          />
        );
      })}
      <Canvas
        camera={{ position: [0, 0, 2] }}
        eventSource={document.getElementById("root")}
        style={{
          pointerEvents: "none",
          position: "absolute",
          top: "0px",
          left: "0px",
          width: "100vw",
          height: "100vh",
        }}
      >
        <Views views={views} />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

const Views = ({ views }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {views.map((view, i) => {
        return (
          <View index={i + 1} key={i + 1} track={view}>
            <Box />
            <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault position={[0, 0, 3]} />
            <OrbitControls makeDefault />
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

const Box = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useFrame((_, delta) => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.rotation.y += 0.2 * delta;
    }
  });
  return (
    <mesh
      ref={ref}
      rotation={[
        Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI,
        Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI,
        Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI,
      ]}
    >
      <boxGeometry />
      <meshNormalMaterial />
    </mesh>
  );
};

// * {
//   box-sizing: border-box;
// }

// html,
// body,
// #root {
//   width: 100%;
//   height: 100%;
//   margin: 0;
//   padding: 0;
// }
```

Modified from Henschel's example
https://codesandbox.io/s/1wmlew?file=/src/App.js